# When on 4 bit data mode, is it possible to use the other 4 bits for other stuff?

Tags: c, avr, lcd

So im writing a C program to interface an LCD on 4 bit data mode. However, I was wondering if I could use the other 4 bits to do something else like an external interrupt. 
To be more specific, Im using PORTD for the data lines on the arduino however I also need pin PD2 to use the INT0 interrupt (pushbutton). In my program I noticed I kept setting the lower 4 bits to 0 when sending commands:

```
PORTD = cmd & 0xf0;
flashLCD();
PORTD = (cmd & 0x0f) << 4;
```

This works perfectly but it sets the other bits to 0. This is called on a timer which means Im sending commands repeatedly. Therefore, I tried saving the previous value of the register and append it with some bitwise operations:

```
uint8_t initial_state = PORTD;
PORTD = (cmd & 0xf0) | (initial_state & 0x0f);
flashLCD();
PORTD = ((cmd & 0x0f) << 4) | (initial_state & 0x0f)
```

It sends the cmd on the LCD, however it still wont respond to the interrupt. I wanted to know if theres something Im not taking into consideration or if my logic is incorrect. Thanks.

Edit: Nvm I figured it out. My LCD library resetted the port register to 0 always even when on 4 bit mode so the other unused ports were being reset as well. I just changed the library so that I can use the other ports when on 4 bit mode.

Comment: When using the 4 bit mode of LCD, the other 4 pins don't even need to be connected to the Arduino GPIOs. So you can use them for anything you wish

Comment: In general, if I have different uses on the same port I will work with a copy in RAM, modify it and write that value to the port. The reasons are a) the port might be write-only and b) reading the port might affect its behaviour, like the status bits related to other uses of the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly noted that other bits can be preserved by using the bitwise operations

```
PORTD = (PORTD & 0x0F) | (high_bits << 4);
```

But! this line is going to be compiled into several machine instructions:

1. load PORTD value into a register
2. perform bitwise AND on the register
3. load high_bits into another register
4. perform other calculations (left shift on the high bits etc.)
5. perform bitwise OR
6. store the result back into PORTD

Let's imagine, somewhere between 1 and 6 an interrupt fires, it stop the code execution, and it changes lower bits of PORTD. After the interrupt routine completes, the program continues to execute and it will rewrite all 8th bits of PORTD by what was stored in the registers before the interrupt, thus overwriting lower bits of PORTD, discarding all changes made in the interrupt routine.

So, there are two approaches to make write operation to PORTx atomic.

*First:* just disable interrupt for the time of PORTx register update:

```
uint8_t old_sreg = SREG; // save SREG register (including I flag)
cli(); // clear I flag, thus prohibiting interrupts
PORTD = (PORTD & 0x0F) | (high_bits << 4); // perform the operation
SREG = old_sreg; // restoring SREG and I flag, if it was set before
```

*Second* approach works only on new AVR cores (eg. ATmega328, 1284, 2560 etc), but will not work on older ones (ATmega8, 32 etc). Refer to the datasheet, *I/O-Ports -> Ports as General Digital I/O -> Toggling the Pin* section.
Writing ones into bits of PINx will invert corresponding bits of PORTx. Using it, it is possible to update only required bits of PORTx register, leaving other intact, thus removing need of locking out interrupts. It may be useful in time-critical environment, where interrupt should fire as quick as possible.

```
PIND = (PORTD ^ (high_bits << 4)) & 0xF0;
```

Of course it will work if it guaranteed the interrupt may change only other (in this example - lower) bits of the PORTD. If the interrupt can also write in the same bits, then this may cause unexpected results, so, be careful.

Comment: Oh nice I didnt think of that thanks. However, isnt it easier to surround the assignment of PORT with cli() at the beggining, and then sei() after? Ex: cli(); PORT = ...; sei();

Comment: @Okbuddydude if you sure interrupts were enabled before, then yes. But if your code called from an interrupt handler or from another routine while interrupts were disabled, careless sei() can produce undesired consequences. That's why it is better to store I flag from SREG and restore it to the previous state

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the controllers (ATmega/AVR or whatever) used on Arduino and you do not even specify, which one you use.

But usually, ports and port pins can be configured to have either input or output mode. Since you give out 4 bits over PORTD, I assume, the whole 8bit port (all port pins) are configured as output.

You should consider your manual, if certain pins of the whole port can be output pins while others can be input pins at the same time and how.

Be careful switching input/output of a whole port in between, it could have side effects, e.g. unwanted H-L / L-H transitions. I had this once with an 8255 output chip, causing resets of my graphic LCD, due to a connected reset line of the LCD.